# in java how to show input dialog message for specific time?

Tags: java, java-io, java-time

In my program I want to show an input dialog box to get an input from the user. But if user doesn't give the feedback within a specific time the input dialog box will be close and the default setting will be run.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;


public class WorkerDemo {





public static void main(String[] args) {

    JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
   final JOptionPane Message = new JOptionPane("do u want to stop  posting?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);


final JDialog getInput = Message.createDialog("Select Yes or No");
final int Option = Message.PROPERTIES;
getInput.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

Message.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
        //super.componentShown(e);
        final Timer t = new Timer(5000,new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Message.setVisible(false);                   
            }
        });
        t.start();
       t.setRepeats(false);

    }
});

Message.setVisible(true);

if (Option == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
      System.out.println("No button clicked");
    } else if (Option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
      System.out.println("Yes button clicked");
    } else if (Option == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
      System.out.println("JOptionPane closed");}

System.out.println("Outside code.");


 }
 }
```

here the problem is if condition is not working. is there any way to solve this problem. thanks in advance.

Comment: Which UI library do you use for show dialogs? You can use [SwingTimer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) or [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) in JavaFX

Comment: I am using "java swing" and "swing timer" but Its not working properly

Comment: show your code snippet

Comment: please check this link i upload my code here : [click to view the code ](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yDzZ4eQ0DA0xJH-VTBJeQWPM95A6fOL38nCLN5mgaNQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It's better to share code here. And what's wrong with it? As I see It works as you want after 5secs. dialog is closed.

Comment: Here problem is, yes and no conditions are not working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version of your code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class WorkerDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
            JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("do u want to stop  posting?",
                                                     JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                                     JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);


            JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("Select Yes or No");
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

            Timer timer = new Timer(5000, e -> dialog.setVisible(false));
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();

            dialog.setVisible(true);

            if (optionPane.getValue() instanceof Integer) {
                int option = (Integer) optionPane.getValue();

                if (option == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                    System.out.println("No button clicked");
                }
                else if (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    System.out.println("Yes button clicked");
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("dialog was closed by timer");
            }

            System.out.println("Outside code.");
        });
    }
}
```

Explanations and notes:

- I chose better names for your variables, and respected the Java naming conventions
- I made the dialog visible/invisible, not the option pane
- I replaced inner classes by lambda expressions, to make the code shorter and more readable
- The option is obtained from the optionPane's `getValue()` method, which returns what the user selected. Your way of initializing it with the constant `Message.PROPERTIES` makes no sense.
- Everything executes, as it should, in the event dispatch thread, thanks to `SwingUtilities.invoeLater()`.
- The timer is simply start just before making the dialog visible. No need for a component listener to do that.
- No need to handle CLOSED_OPTION, since you explicitly told the option pane to do nothing on close: this option is impossible.